# Ajax call inside forEach loop Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am having an Array that contains objects in AngularJS. Based on the value of a property (`snooz`) of these objects I have to call a POST request (`getData.sonnzeUpdate()`). After going through each object in the array, finally, I have to call a GET request. My issue is the GET request (inside the function `$scope.getTableData`) is executed before getting the response (`res` in `.then(function(res){}`) of the POST request.

I have tried with `angular.forEach(`) and `$q`.

Here is my code sample

```
var notifiedAlarms = [];
var d = new Date();
var checkTine = d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + "00";

angular.forEach(snoozedData, function (snoozed_asset, asset_key) {
    if (snoozed_asset.snooz == checkTine) {
        var data = {};
        snoozed_asset.snooz = '';
        data.data = snoozed_asset;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        getData.sonnzeUpdate(data).then(function (res) {
            if (res.status == '200') {
                toastr.info('Alarm with property ' + data.data.actualFailureArea + ' is activated');
                // $scope.getTableData(); //donot want to call it here. as same call will for multiple time
                notifiedAlarms.push(deferred.promise);
            } else {
                // console.log('Error in update');
            }
        });
    } else {
        // no matching snooz
    }
});
$q.all(notifiedAlarms).then($scope.getTableData());
```

Comment: Note that a generator is suitable for this kind of stuff too. Cleans up all the promise stuff. Down level generators still are problematic in TS though.

Comment: here is the updated code

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `notifiedAlarms` is empty at that point: `$q.all(notifiedAlarms)`, because you add the promises to that Array, after they have finished.

And avoid the Deferred antipattern. `getData.sonnzeUpdate()` already returns you a Promise.

```
angular.forEach(snoozedData, function (snoozed_asset, asset_key) {
    if (snoozed_asset.snooz != checkTine) return;
    snoozed_asset.snooz = '';

    notifiedAlarms.push(
        getData.sonnzeUpdate({ data: snoozed_asset }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status == '200') {
                toastr.info('Alarm with property ' + data.data.actualFailureArea + ' is activated');
            } else {
                throw new Error('Error in update');
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your update. Where to call my _$scope.getTableData_ service? My concern is with calling this service.

Answer (score 0):

With `$q.all(notifiedAlarms).then($scope.getTableData())` you're executing `$scope.getTableData()` directly instead of telling it to call it once promises are resolved. Hence, it gets executed earlier than you want.

Change it to `$q.all(notifiedAlarms).then($scope.getTableData);` to get desired behavior.

Here's an example elaborating this:

[**jsfiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3fhqyL8p/2/)

Notice how in the fiddle, I have both ways,

```
myownservice.UpdateSomeData().then($scope.setValue)
myownservice.UpdateSomeData().then($scope.setValue2())
```

And, in HTML only `value` gets updated and not `value2`

Comment: sorry! not working :( same execution.....it goes to service then before getting the response calling _getTableData()_ then showing is toastr

Comment: @SSS can you put up your code in plunker or fiddle to reproduce it with mock API using local JSON files? Can't say what's wrong without looking at working example.

Comment: Yes sure, I will share the link